# I want to send a message in SQS queue to a specific host in a listener fleet.

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I want to send a message in SQS queue to a specific host in a listener fleet. The decision of sending the message to a host depends on the details of the previous run. Can I get any idea about this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is not possible.** The [ReceiveMessage()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html) API call retrieves a message from the queue. There is no ability to request to receive a subset of messages (eg those with a particular attribute, such as `priority=high` or `host=23`).

To accomplish this, you should **create a separate queue** and only have the specific host retrieve messages from that queue.